# Having problems with hasNextDouble method in Java

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

In my program, I have the user input a radius value and then the program outputs the area and perimeter.

I want to make sure the user types in a number, so I used the hasNextDouble() method. It's not quite working correctly, though.

When the program runs the first while loop that I bolded (apparently, I can't bold code, so it's the code with asterisks surrounding it) in my code below, the words "Please enter a number > " appear as intended.

However, if the program runs the second while loop that I bolded (which is nested inside a while loop that tests if the number from the user is positive), "Please enter a number > " appears twice.

I can't figure out why those words are printing twice. Can anyone help?

```
/**
 * Uses the Circle class to calculate area and perimeter of a circle based on a user-provided radius.
 * 
 * @author Brittany Gefroh
 * @version 1.0
 */

//Import the Scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleTest
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //Initialize a Scanner object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create new Circle object
    Circle circle1 = new Circle();

    //Declare variables
    double input;
    String garbage;
    String answer;

    //Do/while loop answer is Y or y
    do
    {
        //Ask user for a radius value
        System.out.print("Enter a radius value > ");

        **while ( ! scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            garbage = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number > ");
        }**

        //Assign user input to the input variable
        input = scan.nextDouble();

        //Test if input is a positive number
        while (input <= 0)
        {
            //Prompt user for a new radius value
            System.out.println("Radius must be greater than 0");
            System.out.print("\nEnter a radius value > ");

            **while ( ! scan.hasNextDouble())
            {
                garbage = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number > ");
            }**

            //Assign user input to the input variable
            input = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        //Run the setRadius method to change the radius
        circle1.setRadius(input);

        //Print blank space
        System.out.println("");

        //Display output
        System.out.println("The radius is " + circle1.getRadius());
        System.out.println("The area is " + circle1.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is " + circle1.getPerimeter());

        //Print blank space
        System.out.println("");

        //Ask user if he/she wants to try again
        System.out.print("Would you like to try again? Y or N > ");
        answer = scan.next();

        //Print blank space
        System.out.println("");

    }while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

}
}
```

Comment: `"Please enter a number > " appears twice.` This may be because you have two `while` loops doing same operation.

Comment: Should that matter? The first while loop runs if the user's first input is not a number. The second while loop runs if the user inputs a number but it's less than or equal to 0. The second while loop will not run unless the input is 0 or less. The two while loops run under different conditions. But if that is the problem, then how would I change it to still check if it's a number and if it's greater than 0?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
answer = scan.next();
```

To:

```
scan.nextLine();
answer = scan.nextLine();
```

Maybe you should try to simplify this code by creating a specialized method for reading double with validation attached to it? Also try to think why you have these 'empty' nextLine() operations. Are these necessary?

edit...

The problem is that `scan.nextDouble();` do not remove EOL marker (End Of Line). The same is with `scan.next();`. That is your issue. EOL marker is analized by *while* condition and it shows:

```
"Please enter a number > " <immediate EOL answer which was left in scanner>
"Please enter a number > " <now we are waiting for user input>
```

Comment: Wait, why would I change the code that deals with the answer String object? The part of the code that isn't functioning properly has nothing to do with that.

Comment: My purpose is to give you a hint where from the issue may come from. Is your scaner cleared after `input = scan.nextDouble();`? :)

Comment: I'm confused because the problem happens way before the code even gets to that part with answer.

Comment: Okay, your explanation makes sense, but I still don't know what that has to do with the answer object.

My problem isn't that those words display twice when the do/while loop runs for the second time if the user types in "Y". My problem is that those words display twice if I type in a non-positive number and then type in a letter, for example, when it prompts me to type in a positive number.

Comment: put `scan.nextLine();` after each `input = scan.nextDouble();` and `answer = scan.next();` to remove EOL from scanner